# Understanding Arel Better

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a before_filter to set a arel relation, but then if I call first in the method it doesn't like it.  It seems to work fine in the console. What am I missing here?

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_team

  def show
    @team.first
  end

  private

  def find_team
    @team = Team.where(:id => params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: It works ok until I wan't to iterate over a has many collection on the object.  I get undefined method `tasks' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing away the result of the call to `first`.  You want to do something like:

```
  def show
     @team = @team.first
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `where` method returns a relation, not an object. To get an object, use the `first` method to return an object (or `nil`) from a relation.

```
def find_team
  @team = Team.where(:id => params[:id]).first
end
```

The `first` method does not update the relation - it returns an object when called on a relation.

Comment: So why does it not work if I call @team.first in the show method after the before_filter?

Comment: Because, as I said, the `first` method does not update the relation - it returns an object when called on a relation. It *returns* an object. When you call `first` in your sample `show` method, you don't *do* anything with the returned `Team` object, and `@team` is still a relation, not a `Team` object.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error, I don't know if it's a typo.

```
def TeamsController < ApplicationController
```

should be

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
```

About the issue, remember you can iterate tasks on a single record, not an array.
In other words

```
@team = Team.where(:id => params[:id])

@team.first.tasks # => OK
@team.tasks # => Not OK, you're trying to call tasks on an Array
```